# Django admin shows wrong list_display in changelist

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to display different fields for different users in Django admin list view (I guess it is called changelist). Django shows correct set of fields for non-super user, but switches between sets of fields for superuser.

I have a superuser and non-super user with a custom permission `perm1` on model defined in `some_app`. The permission is set on non-super user via group.

Below is the code I use to switch `list_display` depending on user.

```
def changelist_view(self, request, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    if user.has_perm('some_app.perm1'):
        self.list_display = (
            'field1',
            'field2',
        )
        make_log('non-super user')
    else:
        self.list_display = (
            'field1',
            'field2',
            'field3',
            'field4',
        )
        make_log('superuser')
    return super(CustomAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, **kwargs)
```

I've tried with and without `list_display` in class definition. No difference.

Django correctly outputs logs (`make_log()`) depending on who accesses that view. But almost half of the time Django shows to superuser set of fields intended for non-super user. And it always shows correct set of fields for the user with the permission `perm1`.

I also tried to use `if not user.is_superuser and user.has_perm('some_app.perm1')` as condition also with no difference. I guess superuser can do everything they want, but doesn't have **permissions** according to Django.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE (thanks [@dirkgroten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252711/dirkgroten)):
Assumption that superuser doesn't have permission is not true in a sense that `some_superuser.has_perm('some_app.perm1')` returns `True` even if the permissions are not set for this superuser explicitly (directly or via group)

Comment: why aren't you using `get_list_display()` method? Also I'm sure you need to exclude `is_superuser` from your condition, because a superuser always has every permission (has_perm() always returns true for a superuser).

Comment: Didn't think about using that method, but will try, thank you.

Comment: @dirkgroten As for using `is_superuser`, I am adding it to the condition because I need to restrict some behavior of some portion of non-super users. That is why I thought `not user.is_superuser` is needed. And then I checked if this non-super user has permission (I would rather call it policy) to differentiate between different groups of non-super user. Can I achieve this without checking `is_superuser`?

Comment: when I said "you need to exclude `is_superuser`" I meant you need to make sure the user is not superuser (i.e. yes, you need to have `if not user.is_superuser` if you want to exclude superusers from your special user group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Django looks at class list_display and not instance list_display.
To have a dynamic list_display, overwrite `ModelAdmin.get_list_display`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_display

Comment: Thanks, will try. But why the set of displayed fields switched for superuser when the condition was `if not user.is_superuser and user.has_perm('some_app.perm1')`?